# How to simulate tsunamis and other natural disasters?

Tags: grass-gis

How do you go about simulating natural disasters like tsunamis? We're mainly looking for a place that might have more too.

Currently, we're trying out GrassGIS's [Tsunami](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Natural_Hazards?fbclid=IwAR2aMEPZISxmdEjtacaw5-5mKZXfGPcGHCGmth-OcGuYXFgAq18uZZeErlI) tool, but it seems to have been discontinued since grass 7, and we're unsure to it because of it

We're also looking into [ClawPack](http://www.clawpack.org/) as well because it was mentioned on ResearchGate. It looks promising as well, but complicated.

We're familiar with QGIS, PostGIS, and prefer to use those tools if possible, but are open to trying new things

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this? I don't really follow what it does.

Comment: Hmm, I meant more how does this help with the Tsunami and natural disasters? I understand what this does

Comment: Ah! Fantastic. Given the function that you mentioned, it takes the inputs: GEOM, start dist and end distance. How do these translate into the distance of effect from a tidal wave and so on?

Comment: Oh! ELI5 means: Explain Like I'm 5 (i.e: consider me a dumbass, so please explain it that way!) 

Googling it right now explains how you might've been confused! XD Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: And here's the [Urban Dictionary Definition](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ELI5) that I was refering to!

Comment: Your question is actually a complex one, it requires modelling of natural disasters (including tsunamis), which are related to many environmental parameters and their visualization (most likely in 3D GIS)...

Comment: Yeah, that's why I was asking if anyone knew of any good software that is able to run those simulations. I've spent all morning trying to find one, but my monkey brain  isn't able to find any (reliable) software that was able to get it all up and running

Comment: Yeah, that's the plan right now

Comment: BTW: the r.tsunami code is here: https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/tree/master/grass6/raster/r.tsunami/ (a Python script)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. An open-ended idea seeking question like this would be fine to ask in the [GIS Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis).

Answer (score 0):

How about using a combination of DEM raster and infrastructure vector data, then using "sink fill" to simulate different flooding scenarios such as: https://gracilis.carleton.ca/CUOSGwiki/index.php/Flood_Risk_Assessment_in_QGIS

You can download the bathymetry data from this site if you need: https://download.gebco.net/